# JavaScript - Child attribute value is automatically changing when changing parent attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, attributes

I am new for drag and drop functionality. Here is may app link in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myzVxq

This is how it works,

1. `data-appt` in **drop** class is used to specify number of **.drag** placed in it. Only two **.drag** can be placed in a **.drop** class.
2. `data-appt` in **drag** class is used to specify height of **.drag** class
   based on `<td>`. `data-appt` value of **drop** class will be changed when
   drag and drop a **drag** class of `<div>`.

Here is my problem,

- when I drag and drop a `.three` class of `<div>` its `data-appt` value is
  change to 1. I don't know why but It should not be changed.
- And I marked the place where the problem exist with help of comment
  in javascript code(/* */).

Please help me, it will be very helpful for me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the codepen example You are changing the `data-appt` of the `.drag` class when changing the drag.

You have to change `.drop` class only. otherwise change the name `data-appt` attribute of `.drag` class to some other name.